# Read from "locked" file in windows using python

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

I have written a python script to process the output file of another program and run various stats on it. Right now, when I attempt to access that file from my python script:

```
with open('C:\\my_file_path', 'rb') as outfile:
     print(outfile)
```

I receive an error message:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\my_file_path'

When using other programs (specifically HxD, the hex editor), Windows gives a more verbose error popup stating:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process.

Running the program as an Administrator, or with sudo from within WSL Ubuntu does not make any difference.

Is there any way to read the data which is being written to this file despite these locking conditions? I cannot mess with the first program as it's a low-level device driver for which I do not have source code. It essentially records data from a hardware sensor and writes it to a file for several hours so being able to concurrently parse that file in python (rather than waiting until the hours-long recording is over) would be much better.

Comment: This is technically not a file-locking error. A lock applies to a range of a file. Locking allows a process to have fine-grained control over read/execute and write/append access to multiple ranges of a file. A failed read or write request due to locking is a lock violation (33). When an existing file is opened, the presence of locks set by other processes has no effect on the granted access to the file as a whole.

Comment: At the coarse level of the entire file, Windows has a different mechanism called the access sharing mode. Every time a file is opened via `CreateFileW` (i.e. create a kernel File object that references the file on disk), the caller must specify the required access and, if any data access is required, whether read/execute, write/append, and delete access to the entire file should be shared. If exiting opens are inconsistent with the required access and share mode, the open fails as a sharing violation (32).

Comment: Note that there's no locking equivalent to delete sharing. Delete access only applies to the entire file, not to ranges of a file. Typically Windows programs that open files for reading or writing do not share delete/rename access. This is why deleting or renaming an open file is usually impossible. If all opens do share delete access, then it's possible for the file to be deleted or renamed even if one or more ranges of the file are locked. However, except for new POSIX support in Windows 10, the system won't actually unlink/delete the file until all references to it have been closed.